# Creating and Referring to a Grand total for a future calculation in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

Attach is a screenshot of my tables and columns/values I have. I am very new to power BI and have searched for a solution to my problem but it all leads to a running total which I does not solve my issue.

I am trying to create a future calculated measure that needs to reference a grand total of total meals as so (grand total total meals * Fairshare %). I could create a column/measure with the grand total written into the equation but i would like to have this column dynamically change since new data will be updated on a monthly basis. The logic should be to have the new column just refer to the grand total meals (whatever value it is; 788150 in this case) multiplied with fairshare % column for each row but I can't see a way to refer to a grand total in power BI.

[image: TTable]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a DAX measure of:

```
Total Meals = [KC_Total_Meal] + [WPP_Total_Meals] + [SP_Total_meals]
```

That measure when it's calculated will be adjusted by the row context in your table. (I'm assuming you have a date or location to the left of your screen print.) If you are new to "context" in Power BI, try reading through [this helpful reference card](https://p3adaptive.com/2015/10/giving-back-steal-this-reference-card/).

To remove the row context to get a true Grand Total, use the [ALL() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax) within a [CALCULATE() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax). ALL() returns all the rows in a table ignoring any filters or row/column context that might have been applied.

```
Grand Total Meals = CALCULATE( [Total Meals]), ALL(Meals_Table))
```

Depending on the situation, you may need similar functions such as [ALLEXCEPT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allexcept-function-dax) or [EARLIER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/earlier-function-dax) or [REMOVEFILTERS()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/removefilters-function-dax).